# 2D Array to 3D Array Javascript (Google Script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

If I have an array:

```
var arr = [ 
            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] , 
            [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] 
          ];
```

How could I convert to

```
var newArr = [ 
               [ [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]          ] , 
               [ [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19] ] 
             ]
```

I tried start from something like `while(arr.length) newArr.push(arr.splice(0,1));` but I am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Google Apps Script has [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but if so, this is the classic use case for it: You want to transform all of the entries in the map into new entries:

```js
var arr = [ 
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] , 
  [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] 
];
arr = arr.map(function(sub) {
  return sub.map(function(entry) {
    return [entry];
  });
});
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If not, or if you don't like all those callbacks, nested `for` loops would do it:

```js
var arr = [ 
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] , 
  [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] 
];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  var sub = arr[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < sub.length; ++j) {
    sub[j] = [sub[j]];
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map old array to the new one.

```
var newArray = arr.map( second => second.map( third => [ third ] ))
```

Or more backwards compatible version

```
var newArray = []
for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i—-){
    var second = array[i];
    newArray[i] = []
    for(var j = second.length - 1; j >= 0; j—-){
        newArray[i][j] = [ second[j] ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Google Apps Script is roughly ES3 compatible (roughly). No chance of arrow functions, I'm not even sure of `Array#map`.

Comment: Is this better? (There might be a typo, did it on iPad)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```js
var arrayify = function(input) {
    var ret = [];
    if(Array.isArray(input)) {
        input.forEach(function(element) {
            ret.push(arrayify(element));
        });
    } else {
        ret.push(input);
    }
    return ret;
};

var arr = [ 
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
    [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] 
];

var newArray = arrayify(arr);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without ES6 could be:

```
var arr = [ 
            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] , 
            [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] 
          ];
var newArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(data,index){
    newArr[index] = [];
   data.forEach(function(d){
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(d);
    newArr[index].push(temp);
   });

})

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Look into [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). If you're creating an array, then looping through another and pushing entries in the one you just created, you want `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient alternative for variety:

```js
arr = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] ]

newArr = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/[^[,\]]+/g, '[$&]') )

console.log( newArr )
```